# Java Development for iOS

Tags: java, ios, ide

I'm developing my work and completion of course it is based on the concept of the Java platform. 
But now ran into a problem the Xcode IDE Apple does not include Java packages.

Is there any tool or extension that will allow me to develop my application for iOS in Java?

Comment: No matter whoever claims, but this is not possible only way to code for iOS is Objective C or Phonegap

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic because it is asking to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource. Please see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse no. Xcode can't and **shouldn't** work with Java or any other language except Objective-C and other languages, based on it.

Comment: Why **shouldn't** Xcode work with Java? I know it can't but why **shouldn't** it? And FYI - Xcode works with C based languages (C, C++, Objective-C, Objective-C++), not Objective-C based languages. And this doesn't even answer the question. The question asks if there is any tool that allows for iOS development in Java. The question is not specific to Xcode.